# Can I enter Croatia from austria with single entry visa Schengen by bus?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, croatia

Can I enter Croatia from Austria with a single-entry Schengen visa by bus, and then return to Vienna by bus ?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Croatia is outside the Schengen area. They do accept dual and multiple entry Schengen Visas but not single entry ones.

http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

Comment: i will enter by bus from vienna not by plane

Comment: @basselzaki Doesn't matter, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](http://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=HR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=VS&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a double or multiple entry C visa issued by
>     a Schengen Member State valid for all Schengen
>     Member States and valid for the period of intended stay.
>     They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days

So only double and multiple visas are valid, and it does **not** matter if you travel by bus, train, ship or plane. Meaning, you need a separate Croatian visa